# Visual Studio Auto Scroll to Bottom After I Paste Something

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code V 1.85.1.Sometimes when i paste a code or line visual studio will auto scroll to bottom. This just happen a few days ago and i am sure i dont's install any new extension or plugin. It's Please help it's really hinder my work

I already disable auto scroll, smart scroll or any setting that make auto scroll but nothing change. I also try reinstalling but still no change.

```
Version: 1.85.1 (user setup)
Commit: 0ee08df0cf4527e40edc9aa28f4b5bd38bbff2b2
Date: 2023-12-13T09:49:37.021Z
Electron: 25.9.7
ElectronBuildId: 25551756
Chromium: 114.0.5735.289
Node.js: 18.15.0
V8: 11.4.183.29-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044
```

Comment: do you have the prettier extension installed?

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77677134/11107541 (possible dup target)

Comment: Yes, i had prettier installed. is it the cause of problem ?

Comment: read my answer post there. I'm particularly curious if workaround in last bullet point works for you. also, still waiting for extension bisect

Comment: Ok so far after i disabled all extension there's no problem. At least for now. Maybe there's problem with the exntesions.

Comment: Thankyou bro. I

Comment: read my comment. I said to do an extension bisect.

Comment: Ok i'll try it.

Comment: After i do extension bisect it's confirmed that prettier is the cause, thank you bro